# Are the IDs reliable?

Tags: clockify

I'm starting to work with the Clockify APIs and I'd like to know if the different IDs are reliable or not? As in, is it a really bad idea to keep ther IDs in my database to know what's what or that's something that would work long term for sure? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

IDs in Clockify represent the identities of their respective entities. They don't change, and are unique across the board, so you can use them in your database if you choose so.

That being said, it's always a good practice when dealing with outside data to assign them your own IDs, that way you're not reliant on contracts that you cannot enforce. Provide every entity with `id` (your own) and `externalId` or `clockifyId` and you won't ever be in position when outside change affected your domain logic.